# Best Javascript framework for RESTful HTTP networking

Tags: javascript, json, http, rest, web

I am more of a backend guy, but frontend development really intrigues me as I make my first steps in seeing the browser as the environment for rich and awesome applications.

What is the most suitable Javascript framework for working with a RESTful HTTP API, in other words, for retrieving (HTTP GET) and submitting (HTTP POST/PUT/DELETE) JSON representations of resources?

I am looking for a framework (if it exists!) that provides good abstraction and encapsulation of HTTP request/response, handles cross-domain and cross-browser issues.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at Backbone.js http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/

Its lightweight, does not have many dependencies (only Underscore.js) and its real easy to use, yet pretty flexible and powerful.

From the site;

Backbone.js gives structure to web applications by providing models with key-value binding and custom events, collections with a rich API of enumerable functions, views with declarative event handling, and connects it all to your existing API over a RESTful JSON interface.

Answer (score 2):

You can use jQuery with its [.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) function. Example:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/users',
    type: 'PUT',
    data: { name: 'John Doe', age: 30 },
    success: function ( data ) {
        alert('John Doe inserted!');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [fetch](https://github.com/github/fetch), it's a lightweight framework that does only fetching (or [unirest.io](http://unirest.io))

```
fetch('/users.json')
  .then(function(response) {
    return response.json()
  }).then(function(json) {
    console.log('parsed json', json)
  }).catch(function(ex) {
    console.log('parsing failed', ex)
  })
```

And please don't use *jQuery* just for `.ajax()` :)